# Several lines of information to a single line

Tags: sql, teradata

I have information about customer's email address and phonenumber, but the data is stored in different tables which results in several rows per customer.

I have my main table with customerId etc. which I need to join with email and phonenumber. To do so I have a "translation" table with a communication_id which connects the tables.

For example

Main table:

```
 CustomerID var1 var2 ...
 123        1    7
```

The translation table which I need to use to connect the main table with the tables that includes email and phone look like this

```
CustomerID CommID
123         780
123         781
123         782
```

And the table with the email could look like this

```
commID email
780     a@a.com
```

and the table with the phone number could look like this

```
commID phone
781     88888
```

what I achieve if I left join the above 3 tables to my main table is

```
CustomerID var1 var2    email    phone
123           1   7      a@a.com     ?
123           1   7       ?       88888
123           1   7       ?          ?
```

I understand why I get 3 rows, but what I want to achieve is a single row like this

```
CustomerID var1 var2 email    phone
123          1     7  a@a.com     88888
```

Thank you
EDIT:

The join syntax is

```
sel * from maintable 
left join Communication on maintable.CustomerID=Communication.CustomerID 
left join email on email.commID=Communication.CommID 
left join phone on phone.commID=Communication.CommID
```

Comment: What is your actual JOIN syntax? You shouldn't be getting three rows, and you should be joining *five* tables (or *seven*), not three.

Comment: Sorry I have made a mistake. I dont have CustomerID in the email and phone table. The join syntax is sel * from maintable left join Communication on maintable.CustomerID=Communication.CustomerID left join email on email.commID=Communication.CommID left join phone on phone.commID=Communication.CommID

Comment: Will there be possibility of multiple email addresses or phone numbers (ie could the record with CommID value = 782 refer to a second record in either of the email or phone number tables). If so what should the result be?

Comment: no it is unique... of course the 'real' problem is a bit more complex with date variables, since a customer could have changed his information. But the real question is how I get all the relevant information into a single line :)

Comment: `teradata`or `mysql`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To combine multiple rows into one you usually do a GROUP BY:

```
SELECT maintable.CustomerID, MAX(email), MAX(phone)
FROM maintable
LEFT JOIN Communication ON maintable.CustomerID=Communication.CustomerID 
LEFT JOIN email ON email.commID=Communication.CommID 
LEFT JOIN phone ON phone.commID=Communication.CommID
GROUP BY maintable.CustomerID
```